# A question on the vertical distance between two environments of the same type

Tags: environments, vertical-spacing, vertical

I defined a new environment for the exercises in my book and it worked well until this point where the distances between two exercises are not the same as follows:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcounter{bt}[chapter]
\newenvironment{bt}[1][]{\refstepcounter{bt}\par\medskip
\noindent \textbf{Bài~\thebt. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
\begin{document}
\section{Bài tập chương I}
\begin{bt}
Viết một chương trình yêu cầu người dùng nhập tên của mình, 
sau đó chương trình sẽ in ra một thông điệp chào mừng người dùng, 
sử dụng tên của họ. \\
Ví dụ, nếu người dùng nhập X, chương trình nên in ra Chào mừng, X. \\
Hãy sử dụng bình luận trong từng bước bài làm của mình để diễn giải mã. 
\end{bt}
\begin{bt}
lesarĂĐkĂÔÂpc
bggcetuƯeyxÔƯ
pyttÂÊĂƯgtvnĐ
ycgƠgkyƠoĐkkb
qiÂÊÊsÊboikƠe
rldÊqclatslsi
ĂatlbnƯĐtdybÊ
omrdrlpxshÂĐi
ƯyƯpivpĐhtrĐa
oiapqocksvvku
ptvvĐtvÂmÊydm
hyĐÔatyalqoÔc
\end{bt}
\begin{bt}
lesarĂĐkĂÔÂpc
bggcetuƯeyxÔƯ
pyttÂÊĂƯgtvnĐ
ycgƠgkyƠoĐkkb
qiÂÊÊsÊboikƠe
rldÊqclatslsi
ĂatlbnƯĐtdybÊ
omrdrlpxshÂĐi
ƯyƯpivpĐhtrĐa
oiapqocksvvku
ptvvĐtvÂmÊydm
hyĐÔatyalqoÔc
\end{bt}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Change the content of 2nd exercise and 3rd exercise to English. The same problem occurs.
- Change the content of 1st exercise into English, the problem solved.
- Change the content of 1st exercise into other Vietnamese text, the problem solved.
- Remove the \ in the 1st exercise and use a blank line after each paragraph, the problem remains the same.
- Remove the last sentence in the 1st exercise and the problem is solved. Remove the first two paragraph, and let only the last sentence in the exercise, then the problem is solved.

My last two actions suggested me that may be the environment changes spacing by the number of characters but when I change the content of the 1st exercises in lengthier Vietnamese text, the problem is solved.

So, what is the problem here?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `\addvspace`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

%\usepackage{parskip}

\newcounter{bt}[chapter]

\newenvironment{bt}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{bt}%
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
  \noindent\textbf{Bài~\thebt. #1}\rmfamily\ignorespaces
}{\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\begin{document}

\section{Bài tập chương I}

\begin{bt}
Viết một chương trình yêu cầu người dùng nhập tên của mình, 
sau đó chương trình sẽ in ra một thông điệp chào mừng người dùng, 
sử dụng tên của họ.

Ví dụ, nếu người dùng nhập X, chương trình nên in ra Chào mừng, X. \\
Hãy sử dụng bình luận trong từng bước bài làm của mình để diễn giải mã. 
\end{bt}

\begin{bt}
lesar ĂĐkĂÔÂpc
bggce tuƯeyxÔƯ
pyttÂ ÊĂƯgtvnĐ
ycgƠg kyƠo Đkkb
qiÂÊÊ sÊboikƠe
rldÊq clatslsi
Ăatlb nƯĐtdybÊ
omrdr lpxshÂĐi
ƯyƯpi vpĐhtrĐa
oiapq ocksvvku
ptvvĐ tvÂmÊydm
hyĐÔa tyalqoÔc
\end{bt}

\begin{bt}
lesarĂ ĐkĂÔÂpc
bggcet uƯeyxÔƯ
pyttÂÊ ĂƯgtvnĐ
ycgƠgk yƠo Đkkb
qiÂÊÊs ÊboikƠe
rldÊqc latslsi
Ăatlbn ƯĐtdybÊ
omrdrl pxshÂĐi
Ưy Ưpiv pĐhtrĐa
oiapqo cksvvku
ptvvĐt vÂmÊydm
hyĐÔat yalqoÔc
\end{bt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg, that helps setting the same vertical space between environment, however I do want to find out why my problem occurs with certain text.